# How can i authenticate users without giving him access to /admin?

Tags: django

I'm using the djangos default auth method with `superuser` but in my system i need to have another login in another dashboard for my customers, if i use the default login methods my customers will have access to `/admin`, is possible to set a differente kind of authentication for my customers and redirect them to a differente dashboard? how?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely: just set [`is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) to False.